# Canvas.observe does not seem to be effective

Tags: fabricjs

I've wrote this :

```
// canvasRoot is a Canvas object
canvasRoot.observe('mouse:down', function() {console.log('<mouse down event>')});
```

But if I click anywhere on my canvas, the event does not seem to be triggered

Answer (score 0):

Check if canvasRoot is an actual fabric.Canvas or the DOM canvas node ^_^

You should also use canvas.on(...) instead of canvas.observe(...) [same function anyway]

Also if you are attaching events to fabric.Canvas objects, you should attach them to **"mousedown"** vs **"mouse:down"** for canvas.

Take a look at source code for more info :)